# FILE Type Not Recognized in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using FILE type in my MFC project but after compiled, it shows the following errors:

```
Error   23  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   24  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   22  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_pFileW'
```

Those errors are referring to this code:

```
FILE *m_pFileW;
```

Did I missing any library header to use FILE syntax? Do I need to use different approach and replace FILE syntax? This errors are only generated when I placed it into my MFC project. This is not happening in C++ Console. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, it lives in stdio, so you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a MFC project you can use [CFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60fh2b6f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class.

For more information about handling files in MFC projects have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey6xh9bk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#include <stdlib.h>` or `<ctype.h>`?